# Inclusion of local rings in integral, separated schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was going through Exercise III.6.8 of Hartshorne, and it boiled down to showing the following:

Let $X$ be an Noetherian, integral, separated, locally factorial scheme, and let $x,y\in X$ be two points. If $y \notin \overline{\{x\}}$, then $\mathcal{O}_y \nsubseteq \mathcal{O}_x$.

(In Hartshorne, it seemed that he is claiming that it's sufficient to show it for closed points $y$, but I don't get this too.)

How do you prove this?

Edit : I wrote a wrong argument here, and erased it.

Comment: That is a homework exercise, so you should probably try to solve that on your own.  I recommend considering the affine case and writing out the condition $\overline{\{y\}} \not \subseteq \overline{\{x\}}$ in terms of the corresponding ideals in the coordinate ring.

Comment: @JasonStarr Is it always possible to assume that there is an affine open subscheme that contains both points? If so, I know how to do the rest.

Comment: No, it is not always possible to find an affine open that contains both -- you can see Hironaka's example in the appendices to Hartshorne.  However, if you choose an open affine that contains $y$ yet does not contain $x$, then the closed complement is the support of a Cartier divisor that does contain $x$.  For a local defining equation $f$ of that Cartier divisor considered as an element in the fraction field, is it contained in $\mathcal{O}_x$?  Is it in the maximal ideal?  What about $1/f$?

Comment: @JasonStarr I see: I didn't know that the complement of an open affine subscheme of an integral separated normal scheme has equi-codim 1. I guess you can pass it to the normalization, restrict to open affine subschemes (use separatedness here), and use algebraic hartogs lemma. (is this right?) Since we have a locally factorial scheme, no need to worry about the rest.

Comment: Yes, the complement of an open affine in a locally factorial scheme is the support of an (effective) Cartier divisor.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your reply! Then I guess you can just consider the line bundle associated to that Cartier divisor. I am happy about this solution, but I don't get what Hartshorne might've intended..

Comment: **correction to my comment: integral separated normal => integral separated (but we have a normal scheme anyway so no need to pass it to the normalization)